# Login student model django

Tags: django, django-models, django-login, django-logging

I am learning django framework and I stuck in a Teacher/student problem.I have student model in which i have students username and password whereas teachers accounts are directly created from admin site users model.I have successfully created login for teachers by using built-in login system of django. Now I wanted to make login of students,their username/password are stored in student models.In my case,student account(username and password) are created by their teachers and are stored in student model.So student only needs to login and i have only one login form (both for teacher and student).
How can I login student by checking from students models.I have searched about it but it makes me confusing.Need some help for this.

here below the login code for Teacher which are created from admin site:

```
       class loginform(View):             
            template_name='IEL/Login.html'
            form_class=UserForm

            def get(self,request):     # if the request is get then only view the function
                form=self.form_class(None)
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

            def post(self,request):
                form=self.form_class(request.POST)

                if form.is_valid():
                    #user = form.save(commit=False)  # it doesnot save in database, it is used to et clean the values
                    # clean data
                    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                    password = form.cleaned_data['password']

                    # authenticate user:
                    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

                    if user is not None:
                        login(request, user)
                        return redirect('IEL:file')
                else:
                    msg = 'Errors: %s' % form.errors.as_text()
                    return HttpResponse(msg, status=400)

                return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: How are we going to help you if we do not see your code? Please post your code

Comment: You should really have every Teacher and Student be a 1to1 to a User. This will ease the conplexity of what you are tryjng to do.

Comment: @Wariored updated

Comment: @MUHAMMADNABEELL1F14BSCS0108 Provide your models.py too

Comment: I have only one  student model at this time: which have student username and password

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to connect both student and teacher to the default user model by one-to-one relationship *(Because both teachers and students are, in the end, users, so it doesn't make sense to have different authentication mechanisms for both)*. 

By this you can make use of django default login system.

You can create 2 groups. One for student, and one for teacher. 
While creating teacher from admin panel, you can add the new teacher to the teachers group.

If you do this, you don't even need to store username and password of student

You can restrict access to some urls for students by making decorators to allow only users belonging to teachers group to access those views.

This may seem complicated, in reality, this is much easier and safer than making your own authentication system.